# How can I add a blue button for "Edit on CodeSandbox" in a Stack Overflow post?

Tags: support, edits

How can I add an "Edit on CodeSandbox" button in the Stack Overflow editor?

Here's [an example of a response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69264263/1264804) with such a button.

Comment: Note that the presence of such a button does not mean the code does not need to be copied to Stack Overflow. See [ask], "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - **but also copy the code into the question itself**."

Comment: Also note that there's no special magic going on here– that "button" is just [an image](https://codesandbox.io/static/img/play-codesandbox.svg), which can then be made a link to CodeSandbox (or anything else really).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image: Edit 50069724/how-to-add-multiple-material-ui-palette-colors]

In the top right of the CodeSandbox toolbar, you have a button labeled "Embed". You click it, then you go to the Other Sharing Options, you copy Markdown and add it to your post on Stack Overflow.

Flow: Embed -> Other Sharing Options -> and you copy Markdown.

Comment: One problem with their embed code is it strips the specific file from the URL. If you wanted to link directly, you can just add `&file=/main.js` (for example)

Comment: When I put the iframe in my post it doesn't show up. Do I need to wrap it in anything?

Comment: There's no such option on my screen. What I did instead was to click on **Edit** in your answer and copy from here, just changing the link.